# Large Table With Multiple Outer Apply Row Compare Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large table with a sample query like below to retrieve matched results.

```
Select col1,col2,col3
from
Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY (select col2 from Table2 Where t2id=T1.id)
OUTER APPLY (select col3 from Table3 Where t3id=T1.id)
Where col3>0
```

problem is the its running extremely slow when I have the Where clause column value check.

I have tried different approach including CROSS APPLY, without any improvement to the performance.

Any idea?

Comment: post query plan....plus table's achema den, plus indexes defined on those tables

Comment: Since you are comparing against a column from the second outer apply you don't need it to be outer but can change it to `cross apply` instead. Might do a difference in the query plan.

Comment: Just a silly question: this query cannot be rewritten as `SELECT T1.col1, T2.col2, T3.col3 FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.t2id LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.t3id WHERE T3.col3 >0`? If the answer is yes, is this query faster, slower or takes the same time?

Comment: @Macro We cant have it that way since some of the APPLY uses FREETEXTTABLE to compute rank for matches.

Comment: I also have tried using multiple Common Table Expression with CROSS APPLY on them, but keeping the col3>0 check. That doesnt seem to do much help. col3 is a computed column, not sure why this filter is making the query that slow!

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the where clause inside the select statement.  This should result in less rows to compute and therefore quicker results

```
Select col1,col2,col3
from
Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY (select col2 from Table2 Where t2id=T1.id)
OUTER APPLY (select col3 from Table3 Where t3id=T1.id Where col3>0)
```